# In Yii2, can I create a file under views and access it directly?

Tags: yii2, view

I have created a file `assets.php` under `/views/accounts/`folder. I cannot access it. It says that localhost tried to redirect to it many times and the page isn't working.

I tried to access it via a button:

```
<?= Html::a('View assets', ['/accounts/assets'], ['class'=>'btn btn-primary grid-button']) ?>
```

and I tried to create an action for it too in my controller:

```
public function actionAssets()
{
        return $this->redirect(['/accounts/assets']);
}
```

but I still, the same error persists.

Is it allowed to just create a view file under the `views` folder? Am I missing something? Or am I doing it wrong? Or it is just not allowed? Thank you very much!

Comment: While acessing through button what you mean by ['/accounts/assets '] i hope i can help you !!! From my experience i think it will be the controller name followed by action name .first do me a reply about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?= Html::a('View assets', ['/accounts/assets'], ['class'=>'btn btn-primary grid-button']) ?>
```

and now you should write a action assets inside **accounts** controller as follows

```
 public function actionAssets() {
 return $this->render('/accounts/assets'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do `render` instead of `redirect` in your action:

```
public function actionAssets()
{
        return $this->render('/accounts/assets');
}
```

Comment: I changed it but there is an error:

strncmp() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given.

What does that mean? i don't have a model for assets. It's just a plain view file. Can it be done?